# Does imbalance not impact returns-calculation weighing when calculating the Sharpe Ratio of an equity Long-Short strategy?

Tags: sharpe-ratio, longshort, market-neutral

I'm calculating the Sharpe Ratio for a simple equity long-short strategy (short stock S and use proceeds to buy stock L). Obviously this is self-financing.

In "https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/51579" it is claimed that the risk-free rate cancels out and can be ignored. This is in line with what I've read (for example in Ernest Chan's book “Quantitative Trading: How to Build Your Own Algorithmic Trading Business 2nd Ed”) which explains:

- the spread between credit and debit rates is "typically small enough to be negligible"
- any margin you need to maintain will anyway appreciate very close to the risk-free rate

*Basically it is acceptable ot ignore the risk-free rate when calculating excess return to use in the Sharpe ratio.* I therefore calculate the "net daily return" of the portfolio as simply the difference between the daily return of each side (L and S) *divided by two* because as per "https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15202" *"The most simple solution is to use the total portfolio notional as the divisor for the PnL. This can be considered the PnL contribution of that long/short sub-portfolio to the total portfolio."*.

Here is an example of my calculations with made-up numbers:

| Stock L |  | Index S |  | Net DailyRet (avg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Close | $DailyRet_L$ | Close | $DailyRet_S$ | $NetDaily_{LS}$ |
| 50 |  | 100 |  |  |
| 75 | 0.5 | 80 | -0.2 | $\frac{0.5-(-0.2)}{2} = \frac{0.7}{2} = 0.35$ |
| 75 | 0 | 60 | -0.25 | $\frac{0-(-0.25)}{2} = \frac{0.25}{2} = 0.125$ |
| 60 | -0.2 | 75 | 0.25 | $\frac{-0.2-0.25}{2} = \frac{-0.45}{2} = -0.225$ |

My question is this:

> The portoflio is only guarabteed to be balanced on day 0. After that, each side may have different daily returns and over time the capital on each side will be not be equal. How is it acceptable to use a "balanced" net daily return (always divided by 2) for the Sharpe ratio, when the portfolio will most likely be unbalanced most of the time?

In other words, why is it ok to use the values of column "Net DailyRet (avg)" in the table above to obtain the mean/stdev for calculation the Sharpe ratio? Do they not become "wrong" (as in an inaccurate representation of net return) as soon as the portoflio becomes imbalanced? Should one not calculate the asset value on the daily and use the respective weights for the long and short side (which would fluctuate daily)?